# Is any dense set connected?

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

In a metric space or a topological space, is any dense set connected?

A set is connected if it cannot be expressed as two disjoint open intervals. Intuitively, it seems clear that a dense set is connected, for instance, taking $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$. However, is this really true? I am unable to come up with a proof.

Comment: Replace "Intervals" with "open sets" for a general metric space, intervals only work for a one dimensional metric space

Comment: The only dense, connected subset of $\mathbb R$ is the whole space itself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The rational numbers are not connected. We can write

$$\mathbb{Q} = \bigg((-\infty, \sqrt{2} ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \bigg) \cup \bigg((\sqrt{2}, \infty) \cap \mathbb{Q} \bigg) $$

Comment: note in this example, those intervals are implicitly written as intervals of rationals only,.  You should probably  change to intersect each interval with $\mathbb{Q}$ explicitly to stick with standard notation

Comment: @Alan woops. Got ahead of myself. Good catch

Comment: Wait, but is $(-\infty,\sqrt{2})\cap \mathbb{Q}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$? If we're looking at connectedness, shouldn't that need to be the case?

Comment: @Clarent Are you aware that open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ are open sets?

Comment: @DionelJaime Yes, I am. But $(\infty,\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ would then be open in $\mathbb{Q}$, and not in $\mathbb{R}$. (I think I clarified my misunderstanding. I will accept, +1)

Comment: @DionelJaime I forgot that when checking for connectedness, we use the subspace topology.

Comment: @Clarent Exactly. In fact, not only is $\mathbb{Q}$ not connected, it's totally disconnected (i.e as non-connected as it gets).